# How to redirect website on specific date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect

Like the title suggest what would be the easiest way to implement a redirect on a specific date in javascript?

I have this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{TIME} >=20190730100000
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20190730110000
RewriteRule ^ google.com [R,L]
```

It works fine, but I would need javascript to redirect if the person is at that time on the page. So basically countdown to the 7/30/2019 10 AM and redirect.

Comment: And if JavaScript is deactivated?

Comment: hmmm any suggestions?

Comment: @johnny456 `<noscript> If you disable JS, this page won't work the way you want it to.</noscript>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reload the page using JavaScript at that date, then the server will redirect:

```
<script>
setTimeout(
  () => location.reload(),
  new Date(2019, 7 - 1, 30, 10, 0, 0) - Date.now
);
</script>
```

Or if you planned to do the redirect using JS that also works:

```
const start = new Date(2019, 7 - 1, 30, 10, 0),
      end = new Date(2019, 7 - 1, 30, 11, 0);

if(Date.now() > end) return;

if(Date.now() > start) redirect();

setTimeout(redirect, start - Date.now());

function redirect() {
  window.location = "https://google.com";
 }
```